# Scheme: Error: #<undef> is not a function

Tags: scheme

I'm newbie to Scheme but what I am trying to write seems to be very simple. Eventhough, there is something I'm missing... I have the following definition:

```
(define (fast-expt x n)
  (if (even? n)
      (expt (expt x (/ n 2)) 2)
      (expt x n)))
```

And it uses my previous function:

```
(define (expt x n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 1)
        ((= n 1) x)
        ((= n -1) (/ 1 x))
        ((< n 0) (* (/ 1 x) (expt x (+ n 1))))
        (else (* x (expt x (- n 1)))))
```

The function `expt` seems to work correctly but when I try to test `fast-expt` it throws me the following: `Error: #<undef> is not a function [fast-expt]`. If it matters, I use the online compiler https://repl.it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [works for me](https://repl.it/repls/HarmoniousBlueLeafbird), but notice that `expt` is missing a closing parentheses. Maybe you need to define `expt` before `fast-expt` in the online interpreter. Or better yet, switch to a good offline interpreter, like Racket :).

Also, the implementation for `fast-expt` must call itself, otherwise it will only work for the first even exponent and from that point on, it'll simply use the "slow" `expt`. It should be implemented like this:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (fast-expt x n)
   (cond ((zero? n) 1)
         ((even? n) (square (fast-expt x (/ n 2))))
         (else (* x (fast-expt x (- n 1))))))
```

Comment: Yes, I have defined `expt` before `fast-expt` but it still doen't work for me. Even when copy-pasting your code it doesn't, so I'm really confused. I'll install and try it in DrRacket editor as well, maybe it's something in the repl.it compiler.. And thank you for your improvement to the `fast-expt` function :)

Comment: @barni I just noticed that your code is missing a closing parentheses, see my updated answer. And I just [tested it on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/HarmoniousBlueLeafbird) and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, running the code in DrRacket it throws me just the same... just a parentheses.. what a stupid mistake! Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: No problem, it was my pleasure :)